# google SSO page is bigger than the popup window

Tags: internet-explorer, showmodaldialog, google-sso

We are using showModalDialog to create a popup window for google SSO. The issue can be seen in the attached image. The window interior is bigger than the content it's self. Every time I make the window bigger the interior gets bigger. This means the user just sees a really big window.

code:

```
function googlesso()
{             
    window.showModalDialog('<? echo constructurl($platform_name,"https") ?>/sso/googlesso','',  'dialogHeight=500px;dialogWidth=900px;scroll:no;'); 
    window.location.reload();
}
```

[image: ie 10 displaying google sso]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chose to use window.open and it works better.